# Time Interval of Dates in Array on a loop

Tags: php

I have an array of datetime queried from a database. I was wondering how to get the time intervals of each dates on a loop in php

Example

```
Array('2014-11-03 13:00:00','2014-11-03 14:00:00','2014-11-03 16:30:00')
```

Should output

```
1:00
2:30
```

Comment: Learning about the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object would be a good place to start.

Comment: Read and try: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: I can use the diff() method of the Date Time Object, however, I can't figure out how to do this inside the loop...

Comment: @StoneDeft That implies that you've tried something. So show what you've tried and explain in what way it failed to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I am now Wondering how this can be achieved on the database level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correction, this code snippet should work as you want:

```
$my_dates = array('2014-11-03 13:00:00','2014-11-03 14:00:00','2014-11-03 16:30:00');
$last_date = null;
foreach ($my_dates as $current_date) {
    $dt = new DateTime($current_date);
    if ($last_date) {
        $diff = $dt->diff($last_date);
        echo $diff->format('%H:%I')."\n";
    }
    $last_date = $dt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Here's My take with for loop:

```
$ar = array('2014-11-03 13:00:00','2014-11-03 14:00:00','2014-11-03 16:30:00');

     for($i=0;$i<count($ar)-1;$i++){
          $d1 = new DateTime($ar[$i]);
          $d2 = new DateTime($ar[$i+1]);
          $time = $d1->diff($d2); 
          echo $time->h.':'.$time->i.'<br />';
    }
```

Cheers !